# Error-Building a maven java servlet project using tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I have added the stacktrace for the errors I am facing. The build is succeeding. But I cannot see the application.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTbgM.png)

My pom.xml goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.colorfulsoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>absoluteclean</artifactId>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

What dependencies should be deleted or added to run this application successfully?

Comment: so it seems to be compiled but is it deployed?

Comment: It is compiling but not getting deployed on heroku. @ScaryWombat

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Tomcat and the version of plugin.

Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin is old and is not maintained anymore. It still can deploy to the newer version of Tomcat. The last Tomcat version the "run" goal is working on is AFAIK the Tomcat 7.